# How to parse xml sibling element value with SED

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a xml file which contains following text:

```
<Cluster>
     <Name>CLS_20</Name>
     <JMXUserName>admin</JMXUserName>
     <JMXPassword>mypwd</JMXPassword>
</Cluster>
<Server>
    <Name>Server_20</Name>
    <IpAddress>a.b.c.d</IpAddress>
    <Port>1234</Port>
</Server>
<Server>
    <Name>Server_21</Name>
    <IpAddress>e.f.g.h</IpAddress>
    <Port>1234</Port>
</Server>
```

I have the IP address of the server (a.b.c.d)
I want to retrieve name of the server (Server_20)

How can this be achieved with SED
Or with any other linux command.

Please help.

Comment: Choose a language that has an XML parser. (Python, Perl, Ruby, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this with sed; it will break horribly when benign formatting changes happen to the XML.

Use a proper XML-parsing tool. For example with xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//Server[IpAddress="a.b.c.d"]/Name/node()' -n filename.xml
```

or with xmllint:

```
xmllint --xpath '//Server[IpAddress="a.b.c.d"]/Name/node()' filename.xml
```

or with old versions of xmllint that don't yet understand `--xpath` (if you are tempted to use this I encourage you to look at other tools):

```
echo 'cat //Server[IpAddress="a.b.c.d"]/Name/node()' | xmllint --shell filename.xml | sed '1d;$d'
```

or with the `xpath` utility from the [`XML::XPath`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-XPath/) Perl library:

```
xpath -q -e '//Server[IpAddress="a.b.c.d"]/Name/node()' filename.xml
```

...or with any of three dozen (dozen) other XML tools.

The heart of this is the XPath expression `//Server[IpAddress="a.b.c.d"]/Name/node()`. This consists of:

- `//Server` refers to a `Server` node anywhere in the document
- `//Server/Name` refers to a `Name` node that is the child of such a `Server` node
- `//Server/Name/node()` refers to the contents of such a `Name` node
- `//Server[IpAddress="a.b.c.d"]` refers to a server node that satisfies the condition `IpAddress="a.b.c.d"`, which means that it has a child `IpAddress` node that contains `a.b.c.d`

Putting all that together, `//Server[IpAddress="a.b.c.d"]/Name/node()` refers to the contents of a `Name` node that is the child of a `Server` node anywhere in the document that has an `IpAddress` child node that contains `a.b.c.d`.

Comment: It is giving me unknown option --xpath when I am using xxllint  : version is- xmllint: using libxml version 20706

Comment: That appears to be an old version of xmllint. Hum. Do you have any other XML-handling tools lying around? There are many that can filter for XPath expressions, so I'd rather look for a tool to use than hack something dirty together with `xmllint --shell` and grep.

Comment: I can not use third party tools since its a customer machine. I am looking for simple and available way to parse that value within a script.

Comment: Okay, then. I edited in a way to do it with old xmllint, but for the record: I don't consider it very pretty. Better than parsing XML with plain-text tools, but still.

Answer (score 0):

Sed is to use with caution on xml due to lot of variation in structure but based on this sample

```
sed -n '
 /<Server>/ h
 /<Server>/,\#</Server># {
   H
   \#</Server># { 
      x
      s#.*<Name>\([^<]*\)<.*IpAddress>a.b.c.d<.*#\1#p
      }
   }' YourFile
```

Principle:

- don't print unless explicitly asked
- load section `Server` in buffer
- when reaching end of section

  - change the whole by keeping only name attribut *if* the ipadresse value is the same as a.b.c and in this case print the result